# Effect of octave on consonance

Tags: theory, chord-theory, pitch, frequency, octave

Was playing around on a keyboard (Casio WK-245, default St.GrPno tone) and I'm noticing that the same chord moved up an octave feels quite different. When I play Cmaj7(no inversions: C,E,G,B in that order) starting at middle C, the chord sounds soft and wistful and a tiny bit "spicier" than say C-chord (which I think is what gives it that wistfulness), but I would characterize it as "quite consonant". On the other hand, when I play it an octave lower it sounds much harsher and very dissonant - it sounds like the same chord, but as if it's groaning or distorted now.

A similar phenomenon seems to happen when mashing a lot of random keys on a piano -- they tend to sound harsher on the lower keys.

Are people less sensitive to dissonance in higher octaves, and if so how does it relate to the ratios between the frequencies of the notes?

My running theory is that our hearing tends to be less precise at higher pitches, but in my experience differentiating notes is actually *easier* for higher pitched ones -- which makes sense to me, since the actual difference in frequencies is much greater (C<sub>0</sub> is 1 Hz less than C#<sub>0</sub>, whereas Bb<sub>8</sub> is about 450 Hz less than B<sub>8</sub>)*

*Potentially this last point is hogwash, since music theory becomes a lot simpler once You replace frequency with log(frequency), which might suggest that our ears process sound as the log of frequency rather than really processing frequencies

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of different variables at work here. There's a combination of subjective psychoacoustics (maybe your "spicy" is my "wispy"), objective mathematics of frequency (yes, an octave difference matters), and certainly not least, issues of musical synthesis and speakers. I used to play around with a small Casio and discovered that certain combinations of keys could create interesting "beat" patterns of interference, not in the air but in the interaction of the tone generators. You might find it interesting to repeat your experiments with an acoustic piano.

Comment: The core "question" in your question, "Are people less sensitive to dissonance in higher octaves," is still a hard one to zero in on. The whole concept of "sensitive to dissonance" is laden with subjective response and cultural assumptions. And of course, once you get into the question of hearing acuity across frequencies, that's unique to each person and physiological. The mathematical part, "how does it relate to the ratios between the frequencies of the notes" might be easier to answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower interval limits](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/lower-interval-limits)

Comment: The cause of this is how our ears decode sound. There are details in the links in the comments.